# Anti Sql injection Library C# Asp.NET

Tags: sql-injection

Can anyone suggest such library for Asp.NET 1.1 ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a quicker solution you can check it out in: http://forums.asp.net/t/1254125.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many to choose from, but in all honesty, your best tool is education.  Knowing how to prevent it yourself.  The tools built into the normal Framework class library are perfectly adequate if used properly.

Simply using parameterized queries and/or stored procedures for every database call is your best prevention.

However, that said, we do use the [Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data%28PandP.31%29.aspx) classes provided with the Microsoft Patterns and Practices library. The ones we use are a bit outdated, but still do the job nicely.  They provide some injection protection and also simplify data access.  But they are not the only, nor necessarily best tool for the job.

More up-to-date information about the current Patterns and Practices library can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx).

Comment: The problem that project is alrady written , and change all stuff to parameterized queries is real pain , So I thought maybe there is some library that will sit in base page and will filder the request ....

Comment: Nope. Sorry. There are such tools for CSRF that I'm aware of, but not something like what you're describing for SQL Injection. Sorry. Given the prevalence and potential damage of SQL Injection flaws (depending on your RDBMS) it might be worth the pain to re-write the data access logic.  Anything out there would require a re-write of any queries using untrusted input regardless.

Answer (score -1):

[Link to Anti-Injection SQL](http://psoug.org/snippet/PHP-Anti-SQL-Injection-Function_18.htm)

```
    <?PHP
        FUNCTION anti_injection( $user, $pass ) {
               // We'll first get rid of any special characters using a simple regex statement.
               // After that, we'll get rid of any SQL command words using a string replacment.
                $banlist = ARRAY (
                        "insert", "select", "update", "delete", "distinct", "having", "truncate", "replace",
                        "handler", "like", " as ", "or ", "procedure", "limit", "order by", "group by", "asc", "desc"
                );
                // ---------------------------------------------
                IF ( EREGI ( "[a-zA-Z0-9]+", $user ) ) {
                        $user = TRIM ( STR_REPLACE ( $banlist, '', STRTOLOWER ( $user ) ) );
                } ELSE {
                        $user = NULL;
                }
                // ---------------------------------------------
                // Now to make sure the given password is an alphanumerical string
                // devoid of any special characters. strtolower() is being used
                // because unfortunately, str_ireplace() only works with PHP5.
                IF ( EREGI ( "[a-zA-Z0-9]+", $pass ) ) {
                        $pass = TRIM ( STR_REPLACE ( $banlist, '', STRTOLOWER ( $pass ) ) );
                } ELSE {
                        $pass = NULL;
                }
                // ---------------------------------------------
                // Now to make an array so we can dump these variables into the SQL query.
                // If either user or pass is NULL (because of inclusion of illegal characters),
                // the whole script will stop dead in its tracks.
                $array = ARRAY ( 'user' => $user, 'pass' => $pass );
                // ---------------------------------------------
                IF ( IN_ARRAY ( NULL, $array ) ) {
                        DIE ( 'Invalid use of login and/or password. Please use a normal method.' );
                } ELSE {
                        RETURN $array;
                }
        }


      [1]: http://psoug.org/snippet/PHP-Anti-SQL-Injection-Function_18.htm


  [1]: http://psoug.org/snippet/PHP-Anti-SQL-Injection-Function_18.htm
```